# How can you unit test a database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing

What are some of the ways? What frameworks can you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a project which does this: http://tsqlunit.sourceforge.net/

Also, Visual Studio Team System for DBA has built-in support for unit testing of Databases.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I presume you mean unit testing your code that hits the database, in which case, there is [NDbUnit](http://www.ndbunit.org/), which appears to be a DbUnit clone for .NET.  I've never used it, but I have used DbUnit, and it is quite useful.

Edit: I assumed you were using .NET because you mentioned MSSQL.  If however you are actually using Java, there is [DbUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/).

Comment: Be aware, the NDbUnit link is going to a totally inappropriate site

Answer (score 1):

[T.S.T. the T-SQL Test Tool](http://tst.codeplex.com/)

> TST is a tool that simplifies the task
>   of writing and running test automation
>   for code written in T-SQL. At the
>   heart of the TST tool is the TST
>   database. This database contains a
>   series of stored procedures that are
>   exposed as a test API. Part of this
>   API is similar with those found in
>   Unit Testing libraries familiar to
>   programmers in C# or Java.