# Unit tests framework for databases

Tags: sql-server, database, unit-testing

I´m looking for a unit tests framework for database development. I´m currently developing for SQL Server 2000, 2005 and 2008.  Do you know of any good frameworks with similar functionality as JUnit and NUnit?
Perhaps it´s better to ask, what do you use to unit test your stored procedures and user defined functions?

Comment: See question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53527/how-can-you-unit-test-a-database-in-sql-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is TSQLUnit... Link here: http://tsqlunit.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use a data access assembly and test that with NUnit using the idea outlined in
http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/articles/dbunittesting.aspx
it uses transactions to rollback changes.  This is not a dedicated database approach but is good if you want to test at a higher level than pure database.

It may be worth having a look at http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2004/07/12/180189.aspx

Comment: I have a feeling that there are occasions when Osherove's technique won't work - such as when you need separate sessions to see committed data.  However, there is undoubtedly some good advice in the article.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using DBUnit in my project. It's quite a good tool to test a database to see if the results you expect are there, but also it can alter the data in a database to predefined values, for example, it will reset a database to the data you were using before the tests, leaving the tables unchanged.

http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

I've also come across T.S.T. the T-SQL Test Tool
http://tst.codeplex.com/