# Unit Testing Stored Procs

Tags: .net, unit-testing, t-sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have some pretty important stored procs that I want to setup automated tests for. I'm using VS2010, Sql Server 2008, MSTest, TeamCity, and PSake. Are there any great tools or frameworks out there that do this?

Comment: are these stored procs called by code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit tests framework for databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202940/unit-tests-framework-for-databases)

Answer (score 1):

it's a little outdated, but http://blog.coryfoy.com/2007/07/test-driving-stored-procedures-in-sql-server-in-vs2008/ gave me a good starting point when i was doing this

Answer (score 0):

I would check out Java and look into JUnit or TestNG. There are some really rich frameworks out there any they tie into TeamCity really great.

Just an option I realize you might be tied to VS2010.